# How to decode base64 strings in a vectorized way within dplyr::mutate?

Tags: r, base64

I have a tibble which contains a column of base64-encoded strings like so:

```
mytib <- tibble(encoded_var = c("VGVzdGluZ3Rlc3Rpbmc=", "QW5vdGhlcnRlc3Q="))
```

When I try to decode it with base64::base64decode

```
mytib %>%
     mutate(decoded_var = base64decode(encoded_var))
```

I receive an error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `decoded_var = base64decode(encoded_var)`.
x `decoded_var` must be size 2 or 1, not 25.
```

I'm looking to have a tibble with a column of decoded, human-readable base64 strings. I'd also like to do that using the mutate tidyverse syntax. How can I achieve that?

Update: The tibble should look like this

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  encoded_var              decoded_var
  <chr>                    <chr>
1 VGVzdGluZ3Rlc3Rpbmc=     Testingtesting
2 QW5vdGhlcnRlc3Q=         Anothertest
```

Comment: ```mytib %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(decoded_var = base64decode(encoded_var))``` is giving me the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base64enc::base64decode` produces a raw vector, so you need to carry out the conversion rowwise and wrap the result with `rawToChar`:

```r
mytib %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(decoded_var = rawToChar(base64decode(encoded_var)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   encoded_var          decoded_var   
#>   <chr>                <chr>         
#> 1 VGVzdGluZ3Rlc3Rpbmc= Testingtesting
#> 2 QW5vdGhlcnRlc3Q=     Anothertest
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `caTools::base64decode` function only works on one string at a time, because a single string could contain several values.  If you always have a single character value in your variable, then you can vectorize it:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mytib <- tibble(encoded_var = c("VGVzdGluZ3Rlc3Rpbmc=", "QW5vdGhlcnRlc3Q="))
mytib %>%
     mutate(decoded_var = Vectorize(caTools::base64decode)(encoded_var, "character"))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   encoded_var          decoded_var   
#>   <chr>                <chr>         
#> 1 VGVzdGluZ3Rlc3Rpbmc= Testingtesting
#> 2 QW5vdGhlcnRlc3Q=     Anothertest
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

EDITED TO ADD:  Actually, there are (at least) four different packages that provide `base64decode` functions.  I used `caTools`.  There are also versions in the `processx`, `xfun` and `base64enc` packages.  (The one in `xfun` is actually named `base64_decode`.)  This is why it's important to show **reproducible** code here on StackOverflow.  The `reprex` package makes this very easy.